# PHP - Get Post like this: contact[id] in a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, post, save

i need your help to grab informations from a api post:

I have two kinds of Post:

The easy one:

```
event=message&token=xyz
```

And the "hard" one:

```
&contact[uid]=123456789&contact[name]=TestUser
```

How can i save " contact[uid] " in a variable?

First idea:

```
$array = array($_POST['event'],$_POST['token'],$_POST['contact[name]']);
```

still not working. Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try `var_dump()`ing your `$_POST` data to see what you get :)

Comment: I know what i get with $postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');

array($_POST['event'] works
but 
array($_POST['contact[name]'] not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 2-dimensional array:

```
$_POST['contact']['name']
```

Comment: Thank you! Its so easy but I did not come up with it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try $_POST["contact"]["name"], that should work...